# What will happen to sharing if 'View All' is removed from Profile?

Tags: criteria-based-sharing

Sharing on an object is configured as follows:

- View All Permission on the Object for Profiles
- Public Read/Write OWD

I now wish to update the sharing settings as follows:

- Remove View All Permission on the object for Profiles
- Make OWD Private
- All Sharing Rules to open up access

Is there any sequence in which the above three should be done?

Will Salesforce recalculate sharing if View All is removed from the Profile?

Comment: Auto-recalculate of sharing rules will take place when you complete step 3, unless you [defer](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.security_sharing_rule_recalculation.htm&type=5) that is.The sequence you have is the way to move forward, Profiles will not recalculate the sharing rules as the “View All” and “Modify All” permissions ignore sharing rules and settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What will happen to sharing if 'View All' is removed from Profile?

If you remove this permission and keep the object at Public Read/Write, given the object permission is still granted (CRUD) all Users of this Profile will continue to have access.

If you remove this permission, have already set your OWD for the Object to Private and not defined sharing rules, Users of this Profile will no longer see all records but only those owned by them or within the hierarchy (if Grant Access Using Hierarchies is checked).

If you remove this permission, set your OWD for the Object to Private and defined sharing rules, records will respect the sharing rules as sharing recalculation takes place once you create the sharing rule.